# saving the model standard out

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have a model that takes several hours to train. The line looks like this...

```
model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                    validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size)
```

When I refreshed the notebook, it has stopped showing the progress. Epoch 8/50 - 75/237 has not changed in the last several hours. Kernel is connected and busy. How will I know when the job is complete?

```
Epoch 1/50
237/237 [==============================] - 2730s 12s/step - loss: 6.6099 - acc: 0.1692 - val_loss: 5.9509 - val_acc: 0.1790
Epoch 2/50
237/237 [==============================] - 2953s 12s/step - loss: 5.7143 - acc: 0.1991 - val_loss: 5.5409 - val_acc: 0.2187
Epoch 3/50
237/237 [==============================] - 2895s 12s/step - loss: 5.3835 - acc: 0.2315 - val_loss: 5.3152 - val_acc: 0.2475
Epoch 4/50
237/237 [==============================] - 2858s 12s/step - loss: 4.6985 - acc: 0.2944 - val_loss: 4.7809 - val_acc: 0.3017
Epoch 8/50
 75/237 [========>.....................] - ETA: 32:28 - loss: 4.1200 - acc: 0.3638
```

1) I do not want to use python command prompt. I will like to know if it is possible using Jupyter.

2) If I interrupt the Kernel will I be able to use the model? I am OK with low level of accuracy because I am just testing the script.

Comment: Will saving the progress to a CSV file be enough for your task.?

Comment: Yes. That will do @SreeramTP

Comment: You can take a look at CSVLogger from keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CSVLogger` from keras for this purpose.

You can find more info regarding it [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger)

A demo usage example is shown below

```
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

filename = 'training_log.csv'
logger = CSVLogger(filename, separator=',')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[logger])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by saving standard out to a file.

```
import sys
oldStdout = sys.stdout
file = open('logFile', 'w')
sys.stdout = file
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
sys.stdout = oldStdout
```

From: 
[How to log Keras loss output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445982/how-to-log-keras-loss-output-to-a-file)

Comment: But this will save intermediate steps too, if the `verbose` is `1`, making the file a mess