# Saving history = model.fit() variable in order to use it again when I start a new VS Code Jupyter Session. Dill and %store does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

So I am doing Transfer Learning with tensorflow and I want to be able to run

```
history = model.fit(...) # Run initial training with base_model.trainable = False
```

After the first training is done, I can fine-tune it by unfreezing some layers so if the first session ran for 20 epochs my next block of code will be:

```
# Train the model again for a few epochs
fine_tune_epochs = 10
total_epochs = len(history.epoch) + fine_tune_epochs
history_tuned = model.fit(train_set, validation_data = dev_set, initial_epoch=history.epoch[-1], epochs=total_epochs,verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Basically it will take the epochs from history and will continue training from the last epoch and save these results in *history_tuned*

But I might want to train it again with more layers unfreezed so I would run *history_tuned02* again and keep using the epochs for each history so my graphs look like one like the image below.
[image: These graph contains the original training session + fine_tuned session]

As you can see from the graph, it's all connected together but in reality is two different training sessions. The first one where the model is frozen and then the fine-tuned session. You can even tell where fine-tuning starts from the bump in performance.

The problem is, for me to do this I have to leave Jupyter open for days, because if I close it, all the variables are gone and I would need to train everything again, which would take insane amounts of time.

I tried using dill package but it would not work on history. I also tried using %store history but it also would not work for some reason as you can see from the image below on a dummy notebook that I test things.
[image: %store does not work on history variable]

So is there a way, to save history variable on disk, close jupyter, open it again, restore history and continue my work? Even if I leave jupyter and VS Code open until I finish with the model, crashes do happen.

Also I use checkpoint callback on tensorflow so I have my weights saved, restoring those is not a problem, but I do need history as well if it's possible.

UPDATE:

When I use CSVLogger callback as suggested and read it with

```
history = pd.read_csv('demo/logs/hist.log')
```

then

```
history.head()
```

The output is

[image: history.head() output]

Comment: Μάριε, έχω  μια ερώτηση: When you run `history = model.fit()` , is the output automatically and stupidly dumped  on the console, as in my case, or have you found a way to prevent this?

Comment: You could use a CSVLogger callback to save the output to a file, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38445982/14774959) out @Apostolos

Comment: Thanks @ClaudiaR. But this would be an abuse and useless writing to file. I prefer seeing this silly progress bar on the console. I have also found that one can use the parameter 'verbose=0' but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have finally patched the trainer to avoid seeing thits stuff at all.

Comment: @Apostolos I don't remember if the output was dumped on the console, it's been a long time but if I remember correctly then yes the output was dumped. I switched to pytorch and my knowledge on Tensorflow is very limited.

Comment: @Marios, I have found out that it has to do with the aparameter 'verbose' when creating a model. The default is 'verbose-auto', which results in 'verbose=1' and this is what cases the dumping on the console. Yet, in my tests, even setting 'verbose=0' doesn't change anything. At some point in the process  'verbose' is set to 1. Because tensorflow-keras is a hell. 

So I believe it is a good thing that you left 'tensorflow' behind you. Most probably, I'll do the same soon! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your history in two ways:

**The manual method:**

Simply interrupt your training and save your history file as a dictionary:

```
with open('/history_dict', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(history.history, file)
```

You can then reload it with:

```
history = pickle.load(open('/history_dict', "rb"))
```

**The automated method:**

You can create a simple callback that every epoch stores your history. So, even if your training crashes, it was automatically saved and can be restored.

The callback can be something like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import os
import csv

my_dir = './model_dir' # where to save history

class SaveHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    if ('lr' not in logs.keys()):
      logs.setdefault('lr', 0)
      logs['lr'] = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)

    if not ('history.csv' in os.listdir(my_dir)):
      with open(my_dir + 'history.csv', 'a') as f:
        content = csv.DictWriter(f, logs.keys())
        content.writeheader()

    with open(my_dir + 'history.csv','a') as f:
      content = csv.DictWriter(f, logs.keys())
      content.writerow(logs)

model.fit(..., callbacks=[SaveHistory()])
```

To reload the history saved as a `.csv` simply do:

```
import pandas as pd
history = pd.read_csv('history.csv')
```

Also I think that besides the custom callback, you can also save the history along your model checkpoints with a [CSVLogger](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/csv_logger/) like this:

```
history = model.fit(..., callbacks=[keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('history.csv')])
```

This can be loaded back with pandas as shown above.

Comment: I just tried CSVLogger and it does work, it saves the file as a csv but the problem is, using pandas to open it again turns it into a dataframe and I try to do print(history.epoch) I get an error saying "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'epoch'". Also thank you so much for writing this, I've been trying to do this for days (I am new to this) and honestly this is the first time I get to do some progress!!

Comment: This is because you're trying to use the dataframe as a dictionary, like History.history was. You have to either access your data differently, using the dataframe or try to convert it back to a dictionary. No problem, I'm happy to help @MariosConstantinou

Comment: Can you post a `history.head()` of your dataframe? I can't remember its structure.  We can try to convert it back to a dictionary, if it is easier for you to use it. Probably with a [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) @MariosConstantinou

Comment: I have updated the question with the output. I will give it a try with the to_dict() function!

Comment: @ClaudiaR, `history = pickle.load(open('/history_dict'), "rb")` raises **"TypeError: load() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)"**. Haven't you checked your code? It should be **`history = pickle.load(open('/history_dict', "rb"))**